# how to limit UTF-8 encoded to URL characters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, string, url

I have a problem with Japanese characters, these characters when converted into URLs become too many, therefore the google API does not support such a long URL

for example:
string:

```
$customerAddress = "日本 〒462-0825 愛知県 名古屋市北区 大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-Handsビル 1F";
```

the same text but in URL encode:

```
%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC+%E3%80%92462-0825+%E6%84%9B%E7%9F%A5%E7%9C%8C+%E5%90%8D%E5%8F%A4%E5%B1%8B%E5%B8%82%E5%8C%97%E5%8C%BA+%E5%A4%A7%E6%9B%BD%E6%A0%B9%EF%BC%93%E4%B8%81%E7%9B%AE+%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%93-%EF%BC%92V-Hands%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB+1F
```

and UTF-8

```
æ—¥æœ¬ ã€’462-0825 æ„›çŸ¥çœŒ åå¤å±‹å¸‚åŒ—åŒº å¤§æ›½æ ¹ï¼“ä¸ç›® ï¼‘ï¼“-ï¼’V-Handsãƒ“ãƒ« 1F
```

the resulting text is too long, causing a zero_results error in [google geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview). if you enter the Japanese text into the tool, you will see that it does not return results until half of the characters are removed

I need a maximum of 220 URL characters for $customerAddress

I tried using PHP urlencode, but the problem is that google does not accept URL characters, it only accepts UTF-8

for example, with this code:

```
    $customerAddress = "日本 〒462-0825 愛知県 名古屋市北区 大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-Handsビル 1F";
    $encoded = urlencode($customerAddress);
    $encodedLimited = Str::limit($encoded, 220);
    $client = new Client();
    $apiKey = Config::get('app.GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY');
    $geocodingUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$encodedLimited&key=$apiKey";
    $result = (string)$client->post($geocodingUrl)->getBody();
```

I get this error:

```
{
   "error_message" : "Invalid request. One of the input parameters contains a non-UTF-8 string.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

I get the same result using `$encoded = utf8_encode($customerAddress);` instead of `$encoded = urlencode($customerAddress);`
How can I make the number of UTF-8 characters already URL encoded to be limited?

Comment: [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/utf8_encode) is almost certainly irrelevant to your problem - it converts from one encoding (Latin 1) to another (UTF-8). If your text is not in Latin 1, do not use that function.

Comment: Just to be clear, the garbage string you show starting "æ—¥æœ¬" is not the UTF-8 representation of your string; your string is probably _already in UTF-8_. It's certainly not in Latin 1, because Latin 1 cannot represent Japanese characters. So it's like if you took a piece of text in English, and then told someone to translate it word by word from French into English - the result would be nonsense, just like that string is clearly nonsense.